# How to apply css to self AND sibling element?

Tags: html, css, hover

so I know how to apply css (obvs) and also how to apply to sibling:

This will apply to #myId ONLY. how do I apply to the hover on (self) AND #myId

```
&:hover ~ #myId {...}
```

this seems to just apply to #myId and hover on self doesn't actually do anything

Comment: I guess `&` is from Sass, `&:hover , ~ #myId {...}`  ?

Comment: that seems to apply it permanently to #myId and hover to current el

Comment: So you want to apply your styles to the element on hover, and, when it's hovered on #myId, `&:hover , &:hover ~ #myId {...}` is probably what you are looking for

Comment: yeh that's it. feel free to answer and I'll mark it correct. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `&` is from Sass,
If you want to apply your style to the hovered element and when it's hovered, to it's `#mydId` sibling, you can use

```
&:hover, &:hover ~ #myId {...}
```